# Collapse labels in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm trying to collapse labels using the Bootstrap in a Symfony project form, but it seems not working as follows :

**File.html.twig**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{
        form_label(form.Text,
                   'Text:',
                   {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-xs-2 control-label'}}
        )
    }}

    <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 440px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text">TEXT</button>
        {{
            form_widget(form.Text,
                        {'attr': {'id': 'text',
                                  'class': 'collapse', 
                                  'placeholder': 'text..', 
                                  'style' : 'height: 200px'}}
            )
        }}
        {{ form_errors(form.Text) }}
    </div>
```

Is there any other way to do it in Bootstrap? Or in any other way but simply?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bootstrap normally works there was one problem rendering your form:

Symfony sets the id attribute automatically. So with `'id': 'text'` you not overwriting symfonys `id` but just add another id attribute e.g.

```
 <input type="text" id="pec_bundle_travelCostsBundle_test_Text" ... id="text" class="collapse" placeholder="text.." style="height: 200px" />
```

In this case bootstrap can not find the data-target `#text`. So just delete the `'id': 'text'` and set the `data-target` attribute to the id symfony sets itself. In my case:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal"
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pec_bundle_travelCostsBundle_test_Text">TEXT</button>
{{
    form_widget(form.Text,
                {'attr': {
                        'class': 'collapse', 
                        'placeholder': 'text..', 
                        'style' : 'height: 200px'}}
    )
}}
{{ form_errors(form.Text) }}
```

You can find out the `id` by viewing the *website source code* with your browser.